# URL Redirection for virtual sub domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, redirect

I have given facility to user to create there own page and also can give url to that page.

For an example i have created one page namely "jkailash" and given url like "jkailash.extrathing". so for that page my final url is like "http://jkailash.extrathing.maindomain.com"

So in front end side i am displaying that page name "jkailash" and on click of that link "http://jkailash.extrathing.maindomain.com" is redirected.

My problem is that while doing this i got "Server not found error",

I have tried given below redirect rules with no success.

`#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.maindomain\.com$   [NC]`
`#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.maindomain\.com$  [NC]`
`#RewriteRule ^ http://www.maindomain.com  [L,R]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've got a `Server not found error` then it means that your DNS is not matching this new subdomain.

You should add a wildcard DNS record in your configuration directing `*.extrathing.maindomain.com` to your server.

Comment: I'm talking about DNS configuration not `.htaccess`. It's not a configuration on your server but with your domain name registrar. Try searching for "DNS wildcard record".

Comment: Thank you for help... what i have to do is. in cpanel under sub domain option have to add new sub domain "*.maindomain.com" , and document root is "/public_html" and now is working .....Thanks.